# jquery validation not stopping form from being submitted

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm tearing my hair out here trying to get a jquery validation to play nicely with my form.

The validation does not appear to be working. The form just submits itself to the page.  I can briefly see the validation error messages appearing before the page submits...

My code:

```
//HTML form
<form id="form_scheduleEvent" name="form_scheduleEvent">
  <label for="name">Name:</label><input class="short" type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <label for="address">Address:</label><input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
  <label for="phone">Phone:</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
  <label for="comments">Comments:</label><textarea name="comments" id="comments" /></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submitRequest" value="Add"/>
</form>


//jquery
//Validation rules
$('#form_scheduleEvent').validate({
rules: {
    name : {required: true, maxlength: 45},
    address : {required: true, maxlength: 45},
    phone : "required"
}
});


$('#submitRequest').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "common/ajax_event.php",
       data: formSerialized,
       timeout:3000,
       error:function(){alert('Error');},
       success: function() {alert('It worked!');}
  });

 return false;
});
```

I tried updating to the latest version of both jquery and jquery.validation....

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

**Update**

```
//The validation is working, but I can't even get the alert to show....
$('#form_scheduleEvent').validate({
 rules: {
   name : {required: true, maxlength: 45}, 
   address : {required: true, maxlength: 45},
   phone : "required",
   submitHandler: function(){
     alert('test');
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're bypassing the plugin completely. You're doing an ajax request separate from the validation. (Sending the form on click instead of submit)

Comment: I know ajax_event.php is working - other jquery on the same HTML and js file is interacting with it using the exact same $.ajax function.

Comment: Grillz - I originally had: if($("#form_scheduleEvent").valid()){$.ajax()...}. I had seen this on a website, but it was giving me an error message saying that .valid is not a function.

Comment: you have it basically right. As paddy shows below you don't need an if statement - just need one function to call the other - either oncubmit -> validate, or have the validate plugin send the ajax on success.

Comment: Just noticed Paddy's answer. Very similar to mine. Either will work depending on how you like your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks everyone for their reply.

I ended up wrapping the ajax call part of my original code in the following code:

```
if($('#form_scheduleEvent').valid() == true){
  //Process ajax request...
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 6):

You should move your AJAX submit call to be fired off by the submit callback in the validate plugin:

```
$('#form_scheduleEvent').validate({
rules: {
    name : {required: true, maxlength: 45},
    address : {required: true, maxlength: 45},
    phone : "required",
    submitHandler: function(form) { DoSubmit(); }
}
});


function DoSubmit(){
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "common/ajax_event.php",
       data: formSerialized,
       timeout:3000,
       error:function(){alert('Error');},
       success: function() {alert('It worked!');}
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this code as well, but had the same error as I mention in my reply to James.

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if you put a rule that doesn't have a matching method, see & vote for my bug report. https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1212

Comment: correct! in my case the culprit was `minLength`: with capital 'L'. should have been `minlength`

Answer (score 2):

You are calling form submission outside of the validation check. You'll probably want something like this:

```
$('#form_scheduleEvent').validate({
rules: {
    name : {required: true, maxlength: 45},
    address : {required: true, maxlength: 45},
    phone : "required",
    success: function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "common/ajax_event.php",
        data: formSerialized,
        timeout:3000
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've got the exact code as shown here, except for the $.ajax part. I've replaced it with alert('test'); because I still can't get this to work. The form IS validating (the error messages are showing if a field is not complete), but it just submits the page without display the alert box.... any more ideas?

Comment: I changed the formHandler to "success" try that.

Answer (score 1):

As Grillz said you are submitting and validating separately, you should explicitely call validation inside your click event to perform it.

Or viceversa as Paddy shows! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Josh Ribakoff
See the bug at: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1212

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form_scheduleEvent').validate({
 rules: {
   name : {required: true, maxlength: 45}, 
   address : {required: true, maxlength: 45},
   phone : "required"
   },
   submitHandler: function(){
     alert('test');
   }

});
```

Submit handler should be outside rule. :-)